# How Post Amount Number From React to Django py script

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

hello i want send data from my react app.jsx to django script file that scirpt have amount variable and need number to give to him in my script

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from . serializer import *
from azbankgateways import (bankfactories,models as bank_models,default_settings as settings,)
import logging
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.http import JsonResponse
# Bank
from azbankgateways.exceptions import AZBankGatewaysException
from azbankgateways.models.banks import Bank


# API
# Create your models here.
# ViewSets define the view behavior.
class BankViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Bank.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BankSerializer


# Bank Functions
def go_to_gateway_view(request):
    # خواندن مبلغ از هر جایی که مد نظر است       
    amount = 5000
    # تنظیم شماره موبایل کاربر از هر جایی که مد نظر است
    user_mobile_number = '+989112221234'  # اختیاری

    factory = bankfactories.BankFactory()
    try:
        bank = factory.auto_create() # or factory.create(bank_models.BankType.BMI) or set identifier
        bank.set_request(request)
        bank.set_amount(amount)
        # یو آر ال بازگشت به نرم افزار برای ادامه فرآیند
        bank.set_client_callback_url('/callback-gateway')
        bank.set_mobile_number(user_mobile_number)  # اختیاری
    
        # در صورت تمایل اتصال این رکورد به رکورد فاکتور یا هر چیزی که بعدا بتوانید ارتباط بین محصول یا خدمات را با این
        # پرداخت برقرار کنید. 
        bank_record = bank.ready()
        
        # هدایت کاربر به درگاه بانک
        context = bank.get_gateway()
        return render(request, "redirect_to_bank.html", context)
    except AZBankGatewaysException as e:
        logging.critical(e)
        return render(request, "redirect_to_bank.html", {})

def callback_gateway_view(request):
    tracking_code = request.GET.get(settings.TRACKING_CODE_QUERY_PARAM, None)
    if not tracking_code:
        logging.debug("این لینک معتبر نیست.")
        raise Http404

    try:
        bank_record = bank_models.Bank.objects.get(tracking_code=tracking_code)
    except bank_models.Bank.DoesNotExist:
        logging.debug("این لینک معتبر نیست.")
        raise Http404

    # در این قسمت باید از طریق داده هایی که در بانک رکورد وجود دارد، رکورد متناظر یا هر اقدام مقتضی دیگر را انجام دهیم
    if bank_record.is_success:
        # پرداخت با موفقیت انجام پذیرفته است و بانک تایید کرده است.
        # می توانید کاربر را به صفحه نتیجه هدایت کنید یا نتیجه را نمایش دهید.
        return HttpResponse("پرداخت با موفقیت انجام شد.")

    # پرداخت موفق نبوده است. اگر پول کم شده است ظرف مدت ۴۸ ساعت پول به حساب شما بازخواهد گشت.
    return HttpResponse("پرداخت با شکست مواجه شده است. اگر پول کم شده است ظرف مدت ۴۸ ساعت پول به حساب شما بازخواهد گشت.")
```

that Amount = 5000 its my custom number to get back to payment but i want amount get from frontend react appliaction

its my react app :

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function AmountForm() {
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/go-to-gateway/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ amount })
    });
  
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
  
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
  };

  function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Amount:
        <input type="number" value={amount} onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default AmountForm;
```

i found this code for app.jsx from OpenAi and its not worked

for my python script in django i use this method for get data from this file but not work:

```
    if request.method.POST == "POST":
       amount_total = request.POST["amount"]
```

Comment: i found how solve this ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for solve this and connect your django script to react
you need method useState or axios in front and send to your api in backend.

you must change your function to API_View for this and then data sent from front
can recived in django scripts :

django Function must change like this :

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

# Create your views here.
@api_view(["POST"])
def register_user(request):
```

and in react useState method can give your API link like this :

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function AmountForm() {
const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/go-to-gateway/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ amount })
});
```

i sent amount from react to django scripts for send it to my payment method in backend .

Solved.

if this help you pls vote up to my answer :)